# Are variables for pass by value variables and local variables in a function not allocated continuously?

Tags: c++, memory, local-variables

I want to know the way variables are allocated on stack, so i make a small test program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    test()
    {

    }
    test(const test &obj)
    {
        cout << "a clone of test has been created" << endl;
    }
};

void foo(test variable_01, test variable_02)
{
    cout << "v3 and v4 have not been created" << endl;
    char variable_03;
    char variable_04;
    cout << "v3 and v4 have been created" << endl;

    cout << "Adrress of variable 01: " << static_cast<void*>(&variable_01) << endl;
    cout << "Adrress of variable 02: " << static_cast<void*>(&variable_02) << endl;
    cout << "Adrress of variable 03: " << static_cast<void*>(&variable_03) << endl;
    cout << "Adrress of variable 04: " << static_cast<void*>(&variable_04) << endl;
}


int main()
{
    test temp;
    foo(temp,temp);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the result

```
a clone of test has been created
a clone of test has been created
v3 and v4 have not been created
v3 and v4 have been created
Adrress of variable 01: 0xbf9dd3ae
Adrress of variable 02: 0xbf9dd3af
Adrress of variable 03: 0xbf9dd37e
Adrress of variable 04: 0xbf9dd37f
```

We have two groups of variable here

- Copies of pass by value variables : v_01 & v_02 (G1)
- Local variables : v_03 & v_04 (G2)

Base on the result, we know G1 have been allocated before G2 (maybe v_01 -> v_02 -> v_03 -> v_04). However there are a some strange things :

- Every variable in each groups are allocated continuously, but G1 and G2 are seem to be a bit far from each other , I think they should all be 0xbf9dd3a_ or 0xbf9dd37_ or { 0xbf9dd3ae -> 0xbf9dd3b1} or { 0xbf9dd37e -> 0xbf9dd381}
- Address of G1 is always greater address of G2. I can explain this base on the way stack work and data segment of a program when loaded. Here is a shortcut of data segment of a loaded program (source : http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf ) .

[image]

- However if my explanation above is right, I can't explain why in each groups, address of variables are base on the time they have been created. (ex : v_03 before v_04, so v_04's address is greater than v_03's one)

Why address of G1 is greater G2, despite being created before G2?

Why variables in each groups are allocated continuously, but these groups are a bit far from each other?

Why address of variables in groups have different order compare to address order between these groups?

Comment: As for why "[the] address of G1 is greater [than the address of] G2", maybe the stack grows downward? Also this is only of interest if you're working on compiler-construction or if you want to learn how to control stack overflows for malicious purposes. For normal day-to-day programming this is of no matter at all.

Comment: Make up your mind whether this question is about C or C++. They're different languages.

Comment: As for C, the standard doesn't even mention stack so the question on how variables are out there is already pointless.

Comment: Are you talking about the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)?

Comment: @kfsone yes, i wan t to talk about it

Comment: There is no stack in the C(++) standard. And C is **strictly** pass-by-value, there is no other method. But that is C++, don't spam tags of different languages!

Comment: @hai_uit if you know it is the call stack, why would you expect variables passed to a function to be contiguous with those inside the function? Where do you think the call information will be stored?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C (not sure about C++ but I suspect it's similar), there is no relationship between addresses of separate objects. The language **does not even define** an order relation on them; the `>`, `<`, `<=`, and `>=` operators have undefined behavior when used on pointers that do not point into the same array.

As for why objects end up with particular relationships between the numeric addresses of pointers to them, that's purely a consequence of implementation details of the compiler and it depends on the specific compiler, compiler version, and options used.

Answer (score 3):

It's compiler-dependent and not part of the standard. The compiler decides how much memory the data will require, reserves blocks of memory for that data, and decides how to allocate it.